# jquery dynamic listview passing data

Tags: jquery, listview, dynamic

im having some beginner problem ... 
the case: a button which appends a li element with id="123" to the ul listview. after clicking this new li element, a new page should appear saying "id 123" clicked.

it kind of works as long as the li element is hard coded and not appended by this button ... whats my fault here?

```
<script>
            var passDataObject = { selectedId: null }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#acclist li").on("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    passDataObject.selectedId = this.id;
                    $.mobile.changePage('#accountdetail');
                });                 

                $("#btn").click(function(){
                    var output = '<li id="123"><a href="#">Test Account</a></li>';
                    $("#acclist").append(output).listview('refresh');
                });                 
            });

            $(document).on( "pagebeforeshow", "#accountdetail", function( e ) {
                $("#details").html(["Selected id is: '", passDataObject.selectedId, "'"].join(""));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="accountpage">
            <div data-role="content">
                <button id="btn">Add</button>
                <br/>
                <ul id="acclist" data-role="listview"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="accountdetail">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="details"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new created DOM are not getting the event, so what you need to do is something like:

```
$('li').live('click',function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id')));
});
```

Comment: $("#acclist li").live("click", function(e){ ... });
thats it ... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the click event you're adding it directly to the element. If you add an element later it won't have the event handler attached unless you do so explicitly, unless you use event delegation. Use $.on() to attach the event handler to a parent object. Then all descendants to add to that parent will automatically have the event hanler attached.

Add the event handler to the `<ul>` element

```
           $("#acclist").on("click","li", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                passDataObject.selectedId = this.id;
                $.mobile.changePage('#accountdetail');
            });
```

Comment: then i get the id of the ul element, not li. but the live() method solves the problem ! thanks